# Same typeid name but not std::is_same

Tags: c++, c++11

Using C++ (gcc 4.8.3) I have 2 types (`T1` and `T2`) which have the strange property that `typeid(T1).name()` and `typeid(T2).name()` are the same but
`std::is_same<T1, T2>::value` is `false`.

How can that be? How can I investigate further to tell what the reason might be ?

Comment: `typeid` ignores top-level qualifiers.

Comment: ^^ which means things like const and &

Comment: @SergeyA so there is practically no use for typeid, or am i missing something?

Comment: @SergeyA There may be no guarantee that `typeid` will give you the *same* `std::type_info` object, but it *is* guaranteed that all `std::type_info` objects returned from `typeid(T)` for the same `T` compare equal. Per C++14 18.7.1/3, `std::type_info::operator==` returns `true` if the two operands describe the same type.

Comment: @Angew, I agree. I will remove my comments.

Comment: @SergeyA: I'd call that a hostile reading of the standard. [type.info]/1 says "suitable for comparing two types for equality", and I think that pretty much precludes silly things like always returning `true`.

Comment: Why would `hash_code` be needed for comparison? It seems more plausible that `hash_code` was introduced to allow sticking typeids into unordered containers. Also, don't confuse the *name* with the value of the typeid result. Nobody is claiming that the *names* have the desired properties (and surely you would not want to hash the name).

Comment: @KerrekSB, I think, I was in the wrong all along. `hash_code` is actually expressed in the terms of equality of typeinfo. (however, with a better worded guarantee still). I fully admit my mistake.

Comment: @SergeyA: No worries - glad we're on the same page in the end.

Comment: @Kerrek SB Compiler implementors love hostile readings of the standard ;-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ignoring polymorphism, `typeid()` gives you an object representing the static type of the expression. But there are certain elements that are ignored when it comes to expression types. From [expr]:

> If an expression initially has the type “reference to `T`” (8.3.2, 8.5.3), the type is adjusted to `T` prior to
>   any further analysis. [...] If a prvalue initially has the type “*cv* `T`”, where `T` is a *cv*-unqualified non-class, non-array type, the type of
>   the expression is adjusted to `T` prior to any further analysis.

As a result, any types which differ only in top-level *cv*-qualification or reference will yield the same typeid. For instance, the types `int`, `const int`, `int&` `volatile const int&&`, etc all give you the same `typeid()`.

Basically, your initial thought process was:

```
typeid(T) == typeid(U) <==> std::is_same<T, U>
```

But the correct equivalence is:

```
typeid(T) == typeid(U) <==> std::is_same<expr_type<T>, expr_type<U>>
```

where:

```
template <class T>
using expr_type = std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>;
```

Comment: I think that another important difference is that (generally) `typeid` is a run time construct and `is_same` is a compile time construct. (I typically prefer compile time constructs).

Answer (score 6):

`typeid` ignores all cv-qualifiers:

> In all cases, cv-qualifiers are ignored by typeid (that is, typeid(T)==typeid(const T))

[(ref)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid)

This means that `typeid` ignores all references `&` and `const` (to name a few).

```
int i = 0;
const int&& j = 1;

if (typeid(i).hash_code() == typeid(j).hash_code()) //returns true
    std::cout << "typeid(int) == typeid(const int&&)";
```

Note that to compare 2 `typeid`s, you have to use either `typeid(T).hash_code()` or `std::type_index(typeid(T))`, because only for those 2 functions is it guaranteed that 2 same `typeid`s will be the same. Comparing references doesn't have that guarantee for example.

> There is no guarantee that the same std::type_info instance will be referred to by all evaluations of the typeid expression on the same type, although std::type_info::hash_code of those type_info objects would be identical, as would be their std::type_index.

[(ref)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid)

---

As, @Yakk mentioned, you can use `std::remove_reference` and `std::remove_cv` to get the behavior you wanted.

`std::remove_reference` removes all references of T and `std::remove_cv` removes all `const` and `volatile` qualifiers. You should pass `T` through these functions before passing them to `std::is_same`, so that `std::is_same` only compares the underlying type (if any) of `T1` and `T2`.

Comment: Their `operator ==` is guaranteed to evaluate `true` for same-type descriptors too. So you cannot reliably compare `&typeid(T) == &typeid(T)`, but you *can* compare `typeid(T) == typeid(T)` and reliably get `true`.

Comment: Mentioning `remove_reference` and `remove_cv` might help the OP solve their underlying problem (and not just their headline problem).