# Assigning to a map iterator causes value change without being a reference

Tags: c++, standard-library

I don't understand why assigning to an iterator->second in a std::map modifies the value into the map

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::map<int, int> lol;
  lol[2] = 33;

  auto it = lol.find(2);

  it->second = 91; // This changes the map's value

  std::cout << typeid(it->second).name(); // This just shows 'int', not a reference

  std::cout << lol[2]; // 91

  return 0;
}
```

isn't `it->second` just an int and not a reference?

Comment: `Typeid` does not tell you if it is a reference.

Comment: @JakeFreeman it doesn't work even with the techniques here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81870/is-it-possible-to-print-a-variables-type-in-standard-c

Comment: @Barry Indeed, it will not. Too late to edit it, I'll just remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> isn't `it->second` just an int and not a reference?

Yes, it is just an `int`. `*it` gives you a `std::pair<int const, int>&`, a reference to the actual value of the node in the `map`. But the member access to `second` is in fact just an `int`. The trait "is a reference" and the trait "is assignable to" are not equivalent - you can assign to non-references, and there are references you can't assign to. `it->second` gives you an *lvalue* of type `int`, that you can assign through, in the same way that:

```
int i = 4;
i = 5; // i is not a reference, but you can assign it here
```

---

That said, `typeid()` wouldn't give you a reference type anyway because reference and cv-qualifications are dropped from type analysis. See also [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36578069/2069064).

*That* said, what you probably want to look at is `decltype((it->second))` (yes, double the parentheses, double the fun). This, in fact, gives you `int&`, because that expression is an lvalue of type `int`.

Comment: Got it, so I'm **dereferencing** the node and then modifying the value directly.. right?